# Closed form for recurrence sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Given the following sequence

$u_0=1$;

$u_1=1$;

$u_n=u_{n-1} + u_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} + u_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor-5}$

($u_n=0$ for every $n<0$)

I would like to find a closed form for this sequence. I googled a lot and I found several methods and tutorials about finding the closed form (e.g. for Fibonacci, linear recurrence relations), but none of them mention what to do if you have terms like $u_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$ in your relations. Does the closed form exist in this case? How to solve it?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are you supposed to do when $n$ is odd?

Comment: Do you possibly mean, e.g., $u_{\lfloor \frac n2\rfloor}$?  Otherwise...well, what is $u_3$?

Comment: lulu is correct, it's $u_{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$ when n is odd. I update the question with this information. thanks